# Is there a way to include a file in Source Control if it's within an "excluded" pattern in Subversion?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using the latest TortoiseSVN and I've got `*.exe` in the global exclusion. But I now find that there are a couple of .exe files that I *would* like to check in.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it manually: right-click the file and choose TortoiseSVN > Add. Ignoring files doesn't mean you can't version them, you're just forced to be explicit about those you DO want to version.

Comment: Duh!  <g>. I had tried that but got a warning (!) icon and thought I'd done something wrong. I just needed to do a Commit on the parent folder. Thanks!